# Get RStudio Viewer pane dimensions programmatically

Tags: r, rstudio

Is it possible to **get** current RStudio Viewer pane dimensions programmatically?

This article describes how to **set** them (height only):

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane

Comment: What's the scenario for which you would like to do this? Depending on how and where you plan to use the dimensions, you may be able to get them from the JavaScript window object inside the pane.

Comment: `rCharts` package allows to set `width` and `height` of the plot to be rendered (inside the Viewer pane) in pixels. So I want to be able to read with R commands the dimensions of the "JavaScript window object inside the pane" and process them into layout of multiple `rCharts` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This currently isn't possible, the RStudio API doesn't seem to expose those parameters at the moment.
That's what I imply from [the reply by RStudio staff here.](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202652986-Get-Viewer-pane-dimensions-programmatically)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 5):

`grDevices::dev.size("px")` returns the width/height of the current graphics device in pixels (and will open the default device if none is already open). Since RStudio's graphics device size is tied to the viewer's size, this function also returns the size of the (non-zoomed) viewer pane.