# RStudio: Get Size of Plot Zoom Window Programmatically

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, rstudio, figure

grDevices::dev.size() programmatically provides the size of the Viewer pane in RStudio.

Is there a similar command (or maybe even a hack) for programmatically obtaining the size of the Zoom window? A brief search of the rstudioapi commands doesn't seem to offer any leads.

Comment: Probably [still not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025827/get-rstudio-viewer-pane-dimensions-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I've been stuck with a similar problem. Have you found the answer?

I went with this solution:

## Start with window

}

```html
x11() # open new window
boxplot(rnorm(100)) # wrtie some good box full of normal values. 
#Plot it! You will see it on the new screen. 
#Now, let's make this loop, and everything will appear. 
while(TRUE){
    cdev <- grDevices::dev.size("cm")
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    cat("Width (cm):", cdev[1], "High (cm):", cdev[2], "\r")
    cat("Press escape to break it.")
}
#Change the new windows number size, and those new numbers will flow.
```

Comment: I an sorry, I mess it a little. IT works of course but the answer was suppose more concise. Let's say, that it is time for sleep.